# GET Request Server Apache

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I get an empty file when I run a get request with parameters

```
  <form method="get" action="iptv-info.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="bid" value="5"/>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="plan" value="11" required=""> 
<input type="button" onclick="myFunctiona5()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Custom List Option" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#category_5">  <br></center>  
<button name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Generate M3U Line </button>  </center>  </form>  </center></div>
```

Is it the correct parameters and how to make a request get..

```
import requests 
s = requests.Session()
URL = "https://cp.fcccam.com/userpanel/iptv-info.php"

def get_clipmails():
    Post_Hdr={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
              'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br'} 
    params='bid=5&plan=11&conx=1&submit=submit'
    html_data=s.get(URL,headers=Post_Hdr,data=params).text

get_clipmails()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using GET Request Method, you need to pass the params inside the params parameter inside the get method.

```py
import requests 
s = requests.Session()
URL = "https://cp.fcccam.com/userpanel/iptv-info.php"

def get_clipmails():
    Post_Hdr = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br'
    } 
    params = {'bid': 5, 'plan':11, 'conx': 1, 'Submit': 'submit'}
    html_data=s.get(URL,headers=Post_Hdr,params=params).text
    print(html_data)
```

Also, if you want to see the result, don't forget to output it inside the `get_clipmails()` method.